# C# Linq or Lambda Expression-How to find duplicate records

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

How to find duplicate records in below mentioned collection structure

**Unique By:**

- CatalogCode, ArticleNumber and Sizename
- CatalogCode, ArticleNumber and SizeIndex

Code:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {        
      ArticleSizes = new List<Sizes>(); 
    }

    public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public int CatalogCode { get; set; }        
    public List<Sizes> ArticleSizes { get; set; }  
}

public class Sizes
{

    public Sizes()
    {        
    }

    public string Sizename { get; set; }
    public string SizeIndex { get; set; }

}
```

**Update:**

I need to find duplicate in below mentioned list

```
     List<Article> ArticleList=new List<Article> ()
        {

        new Article(ArticleNumber ='123',CatalogCode=1,
        ArticleSizes =New ArticleSizes (){
        new Sizes(){SizeName='L',SizeIndex='abc'},
        new Sizes(){SizeName='L',SizeIndex='eee'},
        new Sizes(){SizeName='L',SizeIndex='rrr'}}),

 new Article(ArticleNumber ='435',CatalogCode=1,
        ArticleSizes =New ArticleSizes (){
        new Sizes(){SizeName='XL',SizeIndex='abc'},
        new Sizes(){SizeName='L',SizeIndex='abc'},
        new Sizes(){SizeName='M',SizeIndex='abc'}})

        }
```

Comment: Group by the key and then find groups with a count of more than one?

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: Well, why don't you *try* from that (doing research into grouping by multiple properties first, which there are definitely questions about) and then update your question with what you've tried and what problems you've run into.

Comment: @JonSkeet Technically, wouldn't find duplicates imply, that you do not want the first result, but everything after? So 'count of more than one' wouldn't be totally correct.

Comment: I am trying below mentioned  solution  var duplicateSizeName = ArticleSizeImportList.Select(x => x.ArticleSizes.GroupBy(i => new {CatalogCode=i.CatalogCode,ArticleNumber = i.ArticleNumber.Trim(), SizeName = i.SizeName.Trim() })
                                                                .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)).ToList();

Comment: @Serv: The important thing is to find the *groups* where there's more than one element. What you do with them (keep the first and ignore the rest, or ignore *all* of them) isn't specified by the OP.

Comment: @Rakesh: Please edit this into your *question*, and explain in what way it doesn't work for you - if it doesn't. If it *does* work for you, I'd suggest just deleting this question.

Comment: Hello All Thanks a lot for your help. Finally I did it

Comment: var segmentationList = ArticleSizeImportList.SelectMany(x => x.ArticleSizes)
                                                                 .GroupBy(i => new {CatalogCode=i.CatalogCode,ArticleNumber = i.ArticleNumber.Trim(), SizeName = i.SizeName.Trim() })
                                                                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();